# Checking probability of the if statement in Python more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have multiple variables to pass in if, elif and else statement. Assuming 3 variables a, b, and c. Those are simply list that contains numbers. But I need to define if, elif and else statement for each probability of the variables.

For example:

- if one of the variables >0 do something with this variable but pass the others.

Based on probability I know the all the possibilities and therefore I prepare the code based on these possibilities

```
weeks =9

a=[1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
b=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
c=[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1]
for i in range (weeks):
    if i <= 0:
        (print('this is hypo'))
        
    else:    
        if(a[i] <= 0 and b[i] <= 0 and c[i] <= 0):  # no prod         0
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'no ne is working')
        elif(a[i] > 0 and b[i] <= 0 and c[i] <= 0): # only first      1
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'only a working')
        elif(a[i] > 0 and b[i] > 0 and c[i] <= 0): #first and second  1-2
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'a and b working')
        elif(a[i] > 0 and b[i] <= 0 and c[i] > 0): # first and third  1-3
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i], 'a and c working')
        elif(a[i] <= 0 and b[i] > 0 and c[i] <= 0): # only second     2
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'only b working')
        elif(a[i]<= 0 and b[i] > 0 and c[i] > 0): #second and third   2-3
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'b and c working')
        elif(a[i] <= 0 and b[i] <= 0 and c[i] > 0):     # only third  3
            print(a[i],b[i],c[i],'only c working')
        else:                            # all of are working         1-2-3
            print (a[i],b[i],c[i], 'all wokring')
        print('iteration number :',i)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is finding an efficient way to pass these possibilities in few statements. It is not a big issue to deal with 3 variables, but what happens if I want to pass 10 variables. Do I need to define each probability separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tally up all that are working and if none or all are working then short circuit in a sense, and if only some are then print the ones that are:

```
a=[1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
b=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
c=[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1]

for abc in zip(a, b, c):
    working = [x for x, y in zip("abc", abc) if y > 0]
    print(
        *abc,
        "None" if not working else
        "All" if len(working) == len(abc) else
        "Only " + " and ".join(working),
        "working"
    )
```

Result:

```
1 1 1 All working
0 0 0 None working
1 0 0 Only a working
1 1 0 Only a and b working
1 0 1 Only a and c working
0 1 0 Only b working
0 1 1 Only b and c working
0 0 1 Only c working
1 1 1 All working
```

Comment: Nice logic +1 from my side jab

Comment: I was trying to understand the elif statement that @Jab used but did not get it properly. Is it possible to get an detailed explanation ?

Comment: @Beginner I just updated the answer, if you're talking about the join method it just creates a string where the string join is called on is the delimiter.

Comment: @Jab after the update here is the part that I'm having trouble to understand 
result = [x * z for x, y in zip("abc", abc) if (z := y > 0)]
z = y and greater than 0 and then multiplying this with x  ? Is this correct ? 
Could you expand the explanation little bit ? 
I appreciate it

Comment: When you multiply a string by a number it copies it's contents by that amount so `"a" * 0 == ""`, `"a" * 1 == "a"`,  `"a" * 5 == "aaaaa"`  (btw a boolean is a subset of int either 1 or 0). In a comprehension the condition (`z := y > 0`) is ran before the result `x * y` thus I assign `z` the boolean result then if it's True it then performs the multiplication. In writing this I just figured out I don't need to assign `z` or do the multiplication at all due to `x` already being the desired result I will edit my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

More simplar way?

```
a=[1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
b=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
c=[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1]

a1 = ['working' if int(el)>0 else 'not working' for el in a]
b1 = ['working' if int(el)>0 else 'not working' for el in b]
c1= ['working' if int(el)>0 else 'not working' for el in c]

for f, b,i,x,y,z in zip(a, b,c,a1,b1,c1):
    print(f, b,i,x,y,z)
```

output #

```
1 1 1 working working working
0 0 0 not working not working not working
1 0 0 working not working not working
1 1 0 working working not working
1 0 1 working not working working
0 1 0 not working working not working
0 1 1 not working working working
0 0 1 not working not working working
1 1 1 working working working
```